# C++ errors: ‘string’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors

when I compile the following files, I've got the error:

```
ECArgs.h:36:3: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
```

ECArgs.h:36: ECString value(char c);

Could somebody give me any hints for the error?

ECArgs.h

```
#include <list>
#include "ECString.h"

class ECArgs
{
 public:
  ECArgs(int argc, char *argv[]);
  int nargs() { return nargs_; }
  bool isset(char c);
  ECString value(char c);
  ECString arg(int n) { return argList[n]; }
 private:
  int nargs_;
  int nopts_;
  ECString argList[32];
  list<ECString> optList;
};
```

ECString.h

```
#define ECS gnu

#if ECS == gnu
#include <cstring>
#define ECString string
using namespace std;
#else
#include <bstring.h>
#define ECString string
#endif
```

Comment: It's not a "wired" error. It's perfectly reasonable not to recognize a symbol from a non-included header. Also, `typedef` and `using` are better solutions for type aliases than `#define`.

Comment: @chris What do you mean by non-included header?

Comment: If you want to get access to `std::string`, you need to `#include <string>`, not `#include <cstring>`.

Comment: Precisely what the answer says. `std::string` is in `<string>` and you never include it. Therefore, the compiler is perfectly reasonable in complaining.

Comment: Are you sure that `#if ECS == gnu` does what you think it does? It evaluates `ECS` and `gnu` as integer constant expressions. How is `gnu` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add:

```
#include <string>
```

[cstring](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/) includes function to manipulate C-style string. This version works:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>

#if ECS == gnu
#include <cstring>
#define ECString string
using namespace std;
#else
#include <bstring.h>
#define ECString string
#endif

class ECArgs
{
 public:
  ECArgs(int argc, char *argv[]);
  int nargs() { return nargs_; }
  bool isset(char c);
  ECString value(char c);
  ECString arg(int n) { return argList[n]; }
 private:
  int nargs_;
  int nopts_;
  ECString argList[32];
  list<ECString> optList;
};

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: Just wondering why cstring doesn't work. I tried to use 'string' in another test.cpp file which just include <cstring>. The test.cpp works well.

Comment: @EarthWorm Is possible you includes another header files that included string? I am looking at gcc 4.4.4 and several headers include string, including random and stdexcept.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into a similar error.  It was due to the fact that I had left out `using namespace std;`

Alternatively, one has to use `std::string` for all occurrences of `string`.

Comment: Yes I guess just typing `#include <string>` is not enough, need `using namespace std;`